# Swift Attributed String Clear Background Text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text, fonts

I am trying to make a text title using NSMutableAttributedString, however in the attributes dictionary, I believe I've got the right code, but when I run the code, there's always a gray background, what could I be doing wrong? Or what could I be missing?

```
let titleTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()

    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Wake Up Happy", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.init(name: "Marker Felt", size: 40)!, NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.clear])

    textView.attributedText = attributedText

    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textView
}()
```

I am hoping to get clear background instead of a gray background.

Image with UIColor.clear
[image: Link to image with UIColor.clear]

Tried doing UIColor.blue and still I don't get what's wrong
[image: Tried doing UIColor.blue and still I don't get what's wrong]

Comment: possibly this `gray` background is coming from `UITextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.clear
```

from attribute dictionary.

add

```
textView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set backgroundColor of UITextView as well. Write the following code just before the return statement.

```
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```